# iam using cunning_document_scanner package to scan and crop document.But i need to hide or remove the add more option from the package.hows possible?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: Need to remove the + icon]

Iam using cunning_document_scanner package to scan and crop document. But I

need to hide or remove the add more option from the package. How is that Possible in flutter .
This is my function to scan the document. This function scan the document and save to the local database after converting into the filter. Using this package there is an option to add multiple image when scanning like "+" icon. i need to remove that icon from the UI.

```
void _startScan(
      BuildContext context,
      Resolution resolution,
      String subCatName,
      optional,
      String subCategoryId,
      String categoryId,
      String pageId,
      String filter) async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    try {
      List<String>? scanResult = await CunningDocumentScanner.getPictures();

      if (scanResult != null && scanResult.length > 0) {
        String scannedImageBase64 = scanResult[0];

        File scannedImage = File.fromUri(Uri.parse(scannedImageBase64));

        double preferredWidth = double.parse(resolution.width);
        double preferredHeight = double.parse(resolution.height);

        Uint8List? compressedImageData =
            await FlutterImageCompress.compressWithFile(
          scannedImage.path,
          minWidth: cmToPixel(context, preferredWidth).round(),
          minHeight: cmToPixel(context, preferredHeight).round(),
          quality: 100,
          format: CompressFormat.jpeg,
        );
        if (filter == 'bw') {
          print("b/w");
          Uint8List? bwImageData = convertToBlackAndWhite(compressedImageData!);
          ImageFile = await File(scannedImage.path).writeAsBytes(bwImageData!);
        } else if (filter == 'greyscale') {
          print("greyscale");
          Uint8List? greyImageData = convertToGrayscale(compressedImageData!);
          ImageFile =
              await File(scannedImage.path).writeAsBytes(greyImageData!);
        } else {
          print("color");
          ImageFile =
              await File(scannedImage.path).writeAsBytes(compressedImageData!);
        }

        File resizedImage =  File(ImageFile!.path);

        saveImageToDatabase(
          resizedImage.path,
          subCatName,
          widget.appNo!,
          optional!,
          widget.quickTitle!,
          widget.name!,
          subCategoryId,
          categoryId,
          pageId,
        );

        setState(() {
          imageList.add({
            "path": resizedImage.path,
            "subCatName": subCatName,
            "pageId": pageId,
          });
          isLoading = false;
        });

        if (optional == false) {
          imageoptional += 1;
        }
      } else {
        setState(() {
          isLoading = false;
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

I tried to change the code of the package but did not work for me.